# DataLine sound level meter doesn't show

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm trying this code that I took from `DataLine` doc examples. As far as I understood, it should show an amplitude level meter while the sound is playing, but it doesn't. It opens the sound file and plays it correctly, and shows some data about the file in a small window, but there is no meter.

Maybe I didn't understand the way it works. Can you help me understand?

`DataLineInfoGUI` class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;


 public class DataLineInfoGUI extends JPanel {

PCMFilePlayer player;
JButton startButton;

  public DataLineInfoGUI (File f) {
 super();
     try {
       player = new PCMFilePlayer (f);
   } catch (Exception ioe) {
        add (new JLabel ("Error: " +
                        ioe.getMessage()));
       return;
   }
   DataLine line = player.getLine();
   // layout
   // line 1: name
   setLayout (new BoxLayout (this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
   add (new JLabel ("File:  " + 
                     player.getFile().getName()));
    // line 2: levels
   add (new DataLineLevelMeter (line));
  // line 3: format info as textarea
AudioFormat format = line.getFormat();
 JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
  ta.setBorder (new TitledBorder ("Format"));
 ta.append ("Encoding: " + 
          format.getEncoding().toString() + "\n");
  ta.append ("Bits/sample: " +
             format.getSampleSizeInBits() + "\n");
  ta.append ("Channels: " +
            format.getChannels() + "\n");
 ta.append ("Endianness: " + 
              (format.isBigEndian() ? " big " : "little") + "\n");
   ta.append ("Frame size: " + 
              format.getFrameSize() + "\n");
    ta.append ("Frame rate: " +
              format.getFrameRate() + "\n");
   add (ta);

  // now start playing
    player.start();
 }
   public static void main (String[] args) {
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
  File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
   DataLineInfoGUI demo = 
       new DataLineInfoGUI (file);

    JFrame f = new JFrame ("JavaSound info");
    f.getContentPane().add (demo);
   f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
 }

      class DataLineLevelMeter extends JPanel {
   DataLine line;
   float level = 0.0f;
          public DataLineLevelMeter (DataLine l) {
                line = l;
               Timer timer =
                new Timer (50,
                             new ActionListener (){
                                 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
{
                               level = line.getLevel();
                               repaint();
                           }
                       });
       timer.start();
   }
          public void paint (Graphics g) {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        g.setColor (Color.green);

       int meterWidth = (int) (level * (float) d.width);
        g.fillRect (0, 0, meterWidth, d.height);
  }

}

}
```

`PCMFilePlayer` class:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PCMFilePlayer implements Runnable {
File file;
AudioInputStream in;
SourceDataLine line;
int frameSize;
byte[] buffer = new byte [32 * 1024]; // 32k is arbitrary
Thread playThread;
boolean playing;
boolean notYetEOF;

public PCMFilePlayer (File f)
    throws IOException,
           UnsupportedAudioFileException,
           LineUnavailableException {
    file = f;
    in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream (f);
    AudioFormat format = in.getFormat();
    AudioFormat.Encoding formatEncoding = format.getEncoding();
    if (! (formatEncoding.equals (AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED) ||
           formatEncoding.equals (AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED)))
        throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException (
                                                 file.getName() + " is not 
    PCM audio");
    System.out.println ("got PCM format");
    frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
    DataLine.Info info =
        new DataLine.Info (SourceDataLine.class, format);
    System.out.println ("got info");
    line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine (info);
    System.out.println ("got line");
    line.open();
    System.out.println ("opened line");
    playThread = new Thread (this);
    playing = false;
    notYetEOF = true;
    playThread.start();
}

public void run() {
    int readPoint = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;

    try {
        while (notYetEOF) {
            if (playing) {
                bytesRead = in.read (buffer,
                                     readPoint,
                                     buffer.length - readPoint);
                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    notYetEOF = false;
                    break;
                }
                // how many frames did we get,
                // and how many are left over?
                int frames = bytesRead / frameSize;
                int leftover = bytesRead % frameSize;
                // send to line
                line.write (buffer, readPoint, bytesRead-leftover);
                // save the leftover bytes
                System.arraycopy (buffer, bytesRead,
                                  buffer, 0,
                                  leftover);
                readPoint = leftover;

            } else {
                // if not playing
                // Thread.yield();
                try { Thread.sleep (10);} 
                catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        } // while notYetEOF
        System.out.println ("reached eof");
        line.drain();
        line.stop();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // line.close();
    }
} // run


public void start() {
    playing = true;
    if (! playThread.isAlive())
        playThread.start();
    line.start();
}

public void stop() {
    playing = false;
    line.stop();
}

public SourceDataLine getLine() {
    return line;
}

public File getFile() {
    return file;
}
}
```

Comment: I would try to see if 1) the `DataLineLevelMeter`'s height or width is 0 and 2) [`getLevel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#getLevel--) is returning `AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED` or 0. By the way, I found a copy of that code online that included a comment which says [it's from this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009076.do).

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The getLevel() returns -1.0: probably this is the reason why the meter doesn't show. But why does it return -1.0? It should return a value included between 0 and 1. Had anyone similar issues?

Comment: Update:. if I replace this line: int meterWidth = (int) (level * (float) d.width) with int meterWidth = (int) (0.5* (float) d.width) the meter shows up, but it is of course fixed on the 0.5 value. So the issue is that value -1.0. Please help me: what can be te reason for this weird value?

Comment: @Dav if you're saying its always -1, then this is returning the *AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED* parameter [(see here)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED). The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#NOT_SPECIFIED) specify *...file sizes, frame sizes, buffer sizes, and sample rates...* are causes of the error.

Comment: *"Thank you for your comments."* Tip: Add @Radiodef (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.